# New line if printed text reaches right margin

Tags: c#, printing, document

I am trying to build a notepad application that prints the document you are writing.
The problem is when I print the document, it looks like this:

[image: error]

But I want it looks like this:

[image: good one]

Here is my printing code:

```
private void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            int y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            int z = e.MarginBounds.Right;
            int a = e.MarginBounds.Bottom;

            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(richTextBox1.ForeColor);

            while (linesPrinted < lines.Length)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[linesPrinted++], richTextBox1.Font, brush, new RectangleF(x, y, z, a));
                y += 15;
                if (y >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }
            }

            linesPrinted = 0;
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
```

What can I do to make the program goes down a new line if the current line reaches the right limit?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. More generally, you need to take into account the computed size of the string (see `MeasureString()`) and use that to determine the increment for `y` rather than using the hard-coded value of `15`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks a lot for your help! It solved my problem! I would appreciate if you put your solution as an answer, so I can mark it as valid.

Comment: I didn't really answer the question. I just pointed you in the right direction. You should self-answer, i.e. post your own answer below showing the changes from the code you posted above in the question to the code that eventually worked as you wanted. Make sure you also accept your self-answer, so that the question is clearly noted as answered (which will help others find the same useful answer in the future, as well as avoid having people put more effort into trying to answer, since you already have the answer).